# drawContours differences between linux and windows

Tags: opencv

I find out some differences in drawContour behaviour between Windows and Linux : The following code prints we a filled contour on Windows which is what I expect :

```
drawContours( imIn, contours, -1, color, CV_FILLED, 8 );
```

However on Linux, the contour is drawn but not filled. I am not using the same version of OpenCV ( 2.4.5 on Windows, 2.4.0 on Linux), but has somebody seen something similar ?

Thank you.

Comment: `CV_FILLED` is actually `-1`. Make sure the inputs are identical. Otherwise, play with other versions or debug the source.

Comment: Actually, list of points in countours were differents : they were all repeated one time (why I don't know). With same inputs, results of drawContours are indeed identical. Thanks for the lead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, list of points in countours were differents : they were all repeated one time (why I don't know).
With same inputs, drawContours results are indeed the same.